# How to Convert a Float String to Number?

Tags: excel

A1 is formatted as text and contains a decimal number I would like to programmatically convert to a number.

The "convert to number" function N() only works with whole numbers apparently.

Trying a trick like =A1+0 seems to similarly only work with whole numbers.

Comment: so what does that cell contain any way? I mean the data format.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the function

```
value(A1)
```

to convert a string to a number.

Answer (score 3):

Using VALUE() should work if you know that the cell will convert to a number

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to populate worksheet range from common Data Structures (like DataTable) and still retaining the objects (number, dates, etc.) to get rid of the "convert to number error":

```
string[,] stringArray = new string[dataTable.Rows.Count, dataTable.Columns.Count];

for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < dataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
        stringArray[row, col] = dataTable.Rows[row][col].ToString();
    }
}

...
...

range.Value2 = stringArray;
range.Value = range.Value2;
```

Comment: What programming language is this, and how does it work with Excel??

Answer (score 0):

From Excel 2013 there is a function called `NUMBERVALUE` (listed under Text). You can specify your own decimal and group seperation symbol independently from your computer's region settings. In my own languague it is named `NUMERIEKE.WAARDE`.

[image]